# Creating a new word document if not present

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to create a dashboard in excel using VBA. This is what i am trying to do :

- Create a temporary word file in a specified directory.
- Populate this temporary word document with charts and tables from the excel.
- Mail the document to a person specified in the excel.
- Delete the temporary word file.

So, When i started to code, I used the below statement to open a word document from a directory.

```
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Cells(4, 6) + “Temp.docx”)
```

*Cells(4,6) has the file path

This works, if the file "Temp.docx" is already present in the directory.

What If i want to create a new file "Temp.Docx" if it is not present in the specified directory?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
On Error Resume Next  'allow code to continue even if there's an error
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Cells(4, 6) + “Temp.docx”)
if err.number > 0     'check to see if there's an error
  'if there was an error opening the document, create a new one instead
  Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Cells(4, 6) + “Temp.docx”)
end if
on error goto 0    'reset error handling to stop on error
```

You'll probably want to put better error handling in for your entire code, but this little block should take care of your particular question.

You may also want to confirm that `cells(4,6)` ends with a `\`, or your path\filename won't be correct. You can do that with:

```
if right(cells(4,6),1) <> "\" then
    cells(4,6) = Cells(4,6) & "\"
end if
```

Then you can execute the first block of code knowing that you have the proper delimiter in place

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the early reply. appreciate it. I tried your code.
Meanwhile i use the following statementts after it. to close the word file.<br/> objDoc.Activate
objDoc.Save
objWord.Quit   <br/> I found that the file was not created at all.

Comment: Meanwhile, i used this below code and it worked. Can you tell me if this would cause any problem.   
Dim fpath As String
fpath = Cells(4, 6) + "Temp.docx"
If Dir(fpath) = "" Then
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True
objDoc.SaveAs (fpath)
Else
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fpath, , False)
End If

Comment: It's very difficult to read code in the comments, but it looks like it should be OK to me. If your code is working for you, run with it.

Comment: I think the reason your first version didn't work was that you need to do `objDoc.SaveAs Name:=<something>`. Just doing `objDoc.Save` on a new document will likely not work properly, even though you passed a name to it with `.Add()`.